# In Kotlin Multiplatform how should the Model and ViewModel relate

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm just getting started with mobile app development.  I can see how to build a simple app using `@Composable` functions and the `ViewModel` class from Moko -- `dev.icerock.moko.mvvm.viewmodel.ViewModel`.  What's not clear is how the ViewModel should relate to an underlying model object.  In all the examples of `ViewModel` that I've found, there isn't really a model. There is an immutable uistate object.  For example, based on the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_W5YKPShZ4 :

```kotlin
data class ImageUIState(
    val images : List<ImageData> = emptyList(),
    val selectedCategory : String? = null
) {
    val categories : Set<String> = images.map{ it.category }.toSet()
    val selectedImages : List<ImageData> = images.filter{ it.category == selectedCategory }
}

class ImageViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState : MutableStateFlow<ImageUIState> = MutableStateFlow(ImageUIState())
    val uiState : StateFlow<ImageUIState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun selectCategory( category : String? ) {
        _uiState.update{ it.copy( selectedCategory = category ) }
    }

    ... // Code to initialize _uiState omitted.

}
```

I tried making the object that `_uistate.value` refers to mutable and calling `_uistate.update{ it }` when it changes state.  This did not work in that the call to `update` did not result in a change to the view.  My guess is that after `_uistate.update{ it }`, the framework code sees that the value of `_uistate.value` is the same object as it was before and does not update the parts of the view that depend on the state of that object.

The approach that seems right to me as the model becomes somewhat complex is:

- The model is a mutable object, referred to by a field of the App, and passed to the constructor of the ViewModel object.
- That it would be observed by the `ViewModel` object using the observer pattern.
- When the model changes, the ViewModel's responsibility is to build a new immutable UI state object and to call `_uistate.update`.
- When the model changes, it (or certain aspects of it) should be saved to nonvolatile storage or to the network.

Is this a reasonable idea?  Are there other, more reasonable, approaches?

Comment: I realize that this is more of a question about Jetpack Compose, so I’m adding that tag.  Since I first asked this question, I implemented the approach I suggested and it seems to work ok.  I also found a fairly good discussion in the docs at https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state